# Monetdb - tables size in the database

Tags: monetdb

I've loaded .tbl files in the tables, now how I can see the total space used on the disk by the database?
I'm using Fedora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The disk footprint can be assessed using the (Linux) command 'du' on
>   the dbfarm directory or to run the query 'select * from storage();

Source: http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Userguide/diskspace

Comment: it gives a table with: schema, table, column, type, location, count, type, width, but it doesn't give the size...

Comment: the easiest way to get the size is by running "du" on the farm directory. if you're unfamiliar with the command, there's a quick overview here: http://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-disk-usage-of-files-and-directories/ . if you need the size of a particular table (in bytes), you can run a sum over the "columnsize" column in storage().

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows:

```
mclient -d dwh -f tab -s "select location from storage() where table='name_of_a_table';" | xargs -i du -m /var/monetdb5/dbfarm/dwh/bat/{}.tail | cut -f1 | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Comment: Why only gather the sizes of the tail files? Should the heap and imprint files count as well?